# Nagios: dynamic check_load based on number of cpu/cores/threads, is there something like this?

Tags: nagios

I'd like to make order in our Nagios, in the `check_load` service.

There is no hardware baseline in my company and each server has it's own different specs, which means that the `check_load` script doesn't give the correct results on each server.

I'm looking for a dynamic Nagios check which checks how many processors/cores/threads exist in a server and edits the `check_load` command accordingly based on the numbers found.

Another idea I have, is to use `facter` to get that information and make Puppet edit the local `nrpe.cfg` template based on the findings of `facter` to match best practice load thresholds.

Do you know if such a check exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `check_load --help`:

```
 -r, --percpu
    Divide the load averages by the number of CPUs (when possible)
```

This isn't guaranteed to work on every OS... it uses [sysconf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sysconf) to query the number of CPUs (_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN or _SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF). I seem to recall it not reporting the correct values on AIX. Not a problem on Linux though.

The oldest version I have installed anywhere is 1.4.15, and the -r option is available in that version.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that. Do you know if it has any default values to check against?

Comment: It just toggles "divide by the number of CPUs (cores)" on or off. I guess you could say it defaults to "off", or "divide by 1".